# Como inserir um dado com relacionamento no banco com prisma 2

Tags: javascript, node.js

olá, estou tentando criar um registro no meu banco de dados, preciso inserir as informações de uma mikrotik porem tenho que relacionar a tabela das mikrotiks  com uma tabela de subrede, quando eu criar a mikrotik preciso dizer qual sub rede ela pertence, estou usando o prisma 2 para fazer os cadastros e consultas no meu banco de dados. o meu create do prisma está assim:

```js
await prisma.mikrotik.create({
  data: {
    name: rebody.name,
    ip: rebody.ip,
    netmask: mask,
    gatway: rebody.gatway,
    password: rebody.password,
    Subrede:"preciso inserir aqui qual subrede essa mikrotik pertence"
  }
})
```

se alguém souber como eu relaciono esse registro com um registro já existente na tabela das subredes, e puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

fiz essa mesma pergunta no stackoverflow em inglês e obtive uma resposta que funcionou, o autor da reposta foi um usuário chama @Ryan.
essa foi a resposta que ele passou e funcionou perfeitamente.

Se você adicionou a relação da sub-rede ao mikrotik, o código a seguir deve funcionar bem.

```js
await prisma.mikrotik.create({
  data: {
    name: rebody.name,
    ip: rebody.ip,
    netmask: mask,
    gatway: rebody.gatway,
    password: rebody.password,
    Subrede: { connect: { id: 'id-subnet-desejavel } }
  }
})
```